# Australian TV show, The Magic Boomerang, cricket episode

Tags: tv, episode-identification

Back in the late 1960's/early 1970's the Australian show *The Magic Boomerang* was broadcast in the UK.

I'm reasonably certain I watched an episode where the kid with the boomerang was watching a cricket game in spectator seats, his side were losing due to the decisions of a corrupt umpire. I think this was an important game with a large crowd attending.

He got annoyed and took action, throwing his boomerang and dashing out onto the field while all were frozen, he then moved the ball in flight so it went past the batsman and hit the wicket. After that he dashed to his seat at the back of the grandstand and caught the boomerang just in time.

However a colleague says I'm mistaken and the episode was actually from some other show about a kid with a magic stopwatch that also froze time.

Edit update:

It's clear from the suggested answers that my colleague identified 'Bernards Watch' as the stopwatch time freeze series.....however I saw the other one decades earlier so it looks like the idea was copied.

There is, as proposed, a chance that the cricket match was a very minor part of another Magic Boomerang story, I'm going to look through all the episodes to see.

(I know there were a few where he was on holiday and one or two people became aware of his boomerang, so possibly one of those episodes)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could be [*Bernard's Watch*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0171980/), however, it originally ran from 1997 - 2001 so your time frame might be out.

---

I found this with the Google query `tv show where a kid could freeze time -"out of this world"` and then searching for `bernard's watch cricket` which brought up the YouTube clip.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t watch the video, but the episode your colleague is talking about is from [Bernard’s Watch](https://www.denofgeek.com/uk/tv/bernard-s-watch/53338/revisiting-the-moralistic-quandaries-of-bernard-s-watch):

> When he sees the ball flying towards the boundary, well out of his reach, Bernard decides to pause time and get himself into the perfect position to catch it. Again, nobody seems to notice that he’s just moved instantaneously from one position on the pitch to another.

I was also able to find a list of all the episodes for The Magic Boomerang [here](https://www.classicaustraliantv.com/magboom_eps.htm) (most of which have descriptions). None of the descriptions mention cricket, although there were some that involved horse racing, car racing, and rowing.

Comment: I don't think it was Bernard's Watch ...much earlier when I watched it. Also I deffo remember the kid climbing out of the spectators and dashing across the field, then doing the business and frantically racing back before his boomerang got back

Comment: It was a big important cricket game, maybe at a Test match level

Comment: @DannyMcG If it was an episode of The Magic Boomerang, then the cricket match probably wasn't the main thing to happen in the episode. You should look at [this list](https://www.classicaustraliantv.com/magboom_eps.htm) I found to see if anything looks familiar.